# How are these two normed vector spaces of complex sequences different?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm looking at these two Banach spaces, how are they different?

$l_q := \Bigg\{  x = (x_i)_i \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}} / ||{x}_q|| := \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|{x_i}|^q  \Bigg)^{1/q} < \infty \Bigg\}, (1 \leq q < \infty)$

$c_0 := \Big\{  x = (x_i)_i \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}} / \lim\limits_{i}x_i = 0, ||x||_{\infty} := \sup_{i}|x_i| \Big\}$

I was under the assumption that if a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$, but I was told that $l_q$ and $c_0$ are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the space of all sequences such that their $l^q$ norm as defined in your question is finite, the second is the space of all sequences "vanishing at infinity", with the supremum norm.

The implication you mention only holds in that direction, meaning that the converse does not hold, take e.g. $1/n$. So you can see that one can easily construct sequences in $c_0$ which are not in $l_q$.

Comment: Okay, so if a sequence is in $l_q$, then it is also in $c_0$. But sequences in $c_0$ are not necessarily in $l_q$?

Comment: $1/n$ is one such example, yes.